# How do I use jQuery in google code's wiki

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, wiki, google-code

I have a jQuery plugin up on google code http://code.google.com/p/jquery-html5upload/. I want to have a running example of the plugin on the project home page. How can I go about doing this? I can't figure out to include/use javascript in the wiki pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can for security reasons...

Can't you just post a link to an example site? maybe using [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)?

If jsbin link get reused with time (this is probable but I really can't tell) you can also try using the public folder of [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). It works awesomely well! :D